# EF Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'PATIENT DONOR' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

i am working using EF and I have a table that has an identity property and i tried a lot of solutions but i still get that error.
i defined the property in the class as :

```
[Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PATIENTDONORID { get; set; }
```

and i still get that error and i made the identity option is on in OnModelCreating and i also get the same error

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
           // throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();

            modelBuilder.Entity<PATIENT_DONOR>().Property(x => x.PATIENTDONORID)
              .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        }
```

this is the code that makes insertion and save changes in database:

```
foreach (var item in patient.DONORS)
                {
                    if (item.Checked)
                    {
                        db.PATIENT_DONOR.Add(new PATIENT_DONOR() { PATIENT_ID = patient.PATIENT_ID, DONOR_ID = item.ID});
                    }
                }

               // db.Entry(patient).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
```

What should i do ?

Comment: Can you try turning the 'IsIdentity' property to true from the table in the database. Maybe not the straight forward approach.

Comment: but i want it to be identity in the DB

Comment: You want the column PatientDonorID as the primary key for the table PatientDonor? Right

Comment: exactly.but the user will not enter this column manually .

Comment: Yes. then if you can see your database table, check the properties of the column `PatientDonor`. If the Identity specification is set to false, set it to true

Comment: The error you are getting means that you are trying to set the Identity field yourself. You may have bound the field on your form?

Comment: I am sorry i get confused .it is already identity in DB

Comment: this is the piece of code that i use to insert data into the PatientDonor table:
 foreach (var item in patient.DONORS)
                {
                    if (item.Checked)
                    {
                        db.PATIENT_DONOR.Add(new PATIENT_DONOR() { PATIENT_ID = patient.PATIENT_ID, DONOR_ID = item.ID});
                    }
                }

Comment: I also use Code First and I had no Annotations for the property. Check if your model class name and the ID property has the same name. If the name of your class  is `PatientDonor`, try adding the property as `PatientDonorID`.

Comment: this code of the patient_Donor class is auto generated.and i also tried your solution and changed the name in DB and in the class but i have another error:"FK was not loaded"

Comment: Post the code that *makes the insertion in the question itself*, including the code that actually saves the changes. That's what's causing the problem, not the configuration.  It's very hard to read code in the comments.

Comment: If you try to insert a value from your code into your identity field you will get the message that you have detailed in your post. **I'm not familiar with EF, to be honest, so correct me if I'm wrong**, but if you have a field that binds to the identity column, rather than just evaluating it, whatever handles your data may well attempt to put its own value into the identity column, thus producing the resultant error. Do you have an `INPUT` of any description with `Bind("PATIENTDONORID")` in it?

Comment: i have added the code that make inserting and saving changes to DB in the question now, i wish it became more clear now

Comment: Why did you comment `throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();`?

Comment: because any code comes after it will be not reachable

Comment: Well, I think you're working database first and you should modify the edmx in stead of adding annotations ans fluent mappings.

Answer (score 0):

It is working Correctly now .
I realized that After any change in dB I must remove and redrag tables in model.
and there is no problems in the code itself

Comment: LOL! Wow - I would consider that a bug of the IDE. ;o)

Comment: It is the first time for me  to change the DB after attaching it to the visual IDE ,So i didn't have this problem before